# Best way to retrieve the number of elements in a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab, size, dimensions

I would like to know what is the best way to retrieve the number of element in a vector in matlab in term of speed:

is it:

1. `length(A)`

or

2. `size(A,1)`

Comment: There is also `numel` which is pretty fast. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119739/difference-between-matlabs-numel-and-length-functions) question for a short discussion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither. You want to *always* use `numel` for this purpose. `length` only returns the longest dimension (which can get confusing for 2D arrays) and `size(data, dimension)` requires you to know whether it's a row or column vector. `numel` will return the number of elements whether it is a row vector, column vector, or multi-dimensional array.

We can easily test the performance of these by writing a quick benchmark. We will take the size with the various methods `N` times (for this I used 10000).

```
function size_test

    nRepeats = 10000;

    times1 = zeros(nRepeats, 1);
    times2 = zeros(nRepeats, 1);
    times3 = zeros(nRepeats, 1);

    for k = 1:nRepeats
        data = rand(10000, 1);
        tic
        size(data, 1);
        times1(k) = toc;
        tic
        length(data);
        times2(k) = toc;
        tic
        numel(data);
        times3(k) = toc;
    end

    % Compute the total time required for each method
    fprintf('size:\t%0.8f\n', sum(times1));
    fprintf('length:\t%0.8f\n', sum(times2));
    fprintf('numel:\t%0.8f\n', sum(times3));
end
```

When run on my machine it yields:

```
size:   0.00860400
length: 0.00626700
numel:  0.00617300
```

So in addition to being the most robust, `numel` is also slightly faster than the other alternatives.

That being said, there are likely many other bottlenecks in your code than determining the number of elements in an array so I would focus on optimizing those.

Comment: I posted the same answer but then I removed it. The OP wrote `vector` instead of `matrix`. I think he is considering that one of the dimension of the matrix is one!

Comment: @Sardar_Usama It doesn't matter. The answer is always `numel` regardless.

Comment: `length(A)` and `size(A,1)` or `size(A,2)` also do the same if one of the dimension of the matrix is one. That's what I mean

Comment: @Sardar_Usama I realize they all yield the same result, but `numel` is the correct / most robust way.

Comment: @Sardar_Usama Added a benchmark to demonstrate the actual performance benefits of `numel` as well.

Comment: Your answers are always the best!  